# Show that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^3-2A+I$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda^3-2\lambda+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $v$ be an eigenvector of the matrix $A$ corresponding to the
>   eigenvalue $\lambda$.
>
> Show that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^3-2A+I$ corresponding to
>   the eigenvalue $\lambda^3-2\lambda+1$.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't manage to get to a solution without assuming A is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A^3-2A+I)v=A^3v-2Av+Iv=AAAv-2\lambda v+v=\lambda^3v-2\lambda v+v=(\lambda ^3-2\lambda+1)v$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ if $Av = \lambda v$. The result holds quickly upon multiplying by $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

as  a first step prove, by induction that if $Av=\lambda v$ ( $v$ is an eigenvector of the eigenvalue $\lambda$) then $A^nv=\lambda^n v$.

than prove that if $v$ is a common eigenvector for two matrices $Av=\lambda v$ and $Bv=\mu v$ then $(A+B)v=(\lambda+\mu)v$